# Texto borrado ao ativar Canvas

Tags: c#, unity-5

Imagem como deveria ser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem borrada depois de desativar primeiro *Canvas*, e ativar outro *Canvas*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu uso dois *Canvas* na mesma *Scene*, um para o login, que inicia ativado, outro para o registro que inicia desativado, e quando o botão registrar é clicado, ele ativa o *Canvas* de registro.

```
void TaskOnClick()
    {
        CanvasLogin.enabled = false;
        LoginValue.text = "";
        PasswordValue.text = "";
        CanvasRegister.enabled = true;
    }
```

Mas depois que o botão registar é clicado, o *Canvas* fica borrado, a configuração dos dois é idêntica, e um detalhe: qualquer alteração nos campos/tela o *Canvas* é renderizado corretamente...

O Canvas está configurado pra escalar conforme o tamanho da tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Nota:**

> O problema não é que o Canvas está borrado, e sim que fica borrado
>   depois de ativar por comando.

Comment: Não estou muito por dentro do unity, mas experimenta `Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases`  [Veja a documentação do Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases.html)

Comment: @lazyFox tentei aqui agora e também não foi, to começando achar que esse Unity ta bugadão heheh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi aumentando a resolução de referencia, de 800x600 pra 1920x1080.

Mas não sei dizer a causa da imagem ficar borrada somente quando eu ativava o Canvas por comando, pois ela iniciava normal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]